# Using underlying POI object in Spoiwo

Tags: scala, apache-poi, spoiwo

I found the [Spoiwo](https://github.com/norbert-radyk/spoiwo) library for Scala/Excel generation. However for my spreadsheet I need to use [data validations](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation) as well.

It seems that Spoiwo does not support that feature yet. Can I access the underlying POI object somehow to use the `sheet.addValidationData` method directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct Spoiwo does not yet support data validations (though as it's an open source library always feel free to send a pull request to add those ;).

You can definitely use the underlying POI object to achieve what you require:

1. Just define the Sheet in Spoiwo as you would do normally.

   ```
   val sheet = Sheet(name = "My awesome sheet")
   ```
2. Convert the sheet to the original XLSX POI object, by importing the XLSX nature and converting the sheet (please note you can either convert the sheet creating new POI workbook with a single sheet or add the sheet to the existing POI workbook):

   ```
   import com.norbitltd.spoiwo.natures.xlsx.Model2XlsxConversions._

   //Creates a new POI workbook with a single sheet
   val poiWorkbook = sheet.convertAsXlsx()
   ```
3. Use the POI workbook as you would do normally

   ```
   poiWorkbook.getSheet(1).addValidationData(...)
   ```

Comment: How do you then convert the `poiWorkdbook` back to a SPOIWO `Workbook` to use the SPOIWO wrapper?

Comment: never mind - I looked at the natures and models, looks like it's a one way street.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, at the moment SPOIWO supports only one way conversion. Though it's an open source project, so feel free to add the POI => SPOIWO conversion should you need one.